# Getting from Bloomington to Indianapolis Airport for an early flight?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, indiana, ind

Is there any way to get from Bloomington (Indiana) to Indianapolis Airport for an early flight (pre-7am) by public transport?

My normal go-to for this sort of thing is Google Maps, but that doesn't have any public transport options shown for the route. I've tried [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Bloomington-IN-USA/Indianapolis-Airport-IND), which did suggest several good options for later in the day, but alas none that arrive in time

Hiring a car is certainly one option, as is taking the [last Bloomington Airport Shuttle](https://goexpresstravel.com/airport_shuttle_schedule#schedule) the night before and trying to find a cheap hotel at the airport.

Before committing to one of those options, I'm wondering - are there any other public transport options that might get you to the airport for a little before 6am?

Comment: When I did this in 1991, I took the Greyhound bus. I presume you've considered that option already?

Comment: The Greyhound website is only showing me two coaches a day, one around lunchtime and one late afternoon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Star of America Shuttle has service](http://www.soashuttle.com/locations/bloomington-to-indianapolis/) picking up at various points in Bloomington and arriving at the airport at 6:10 am. That's pretty tight but it may be doable if you can check in and get through security quickly. [Another shuttle](http://goexpresstravel.com/airport_shuttle_schedule) has a 6:30am scheduled arrival, but that's certainly not enough time.

It seems that Uber is also available.

Comment: There are also probably cabs or perhaps some limo services in the area but since when is Uber a “public transport option”?

Comment: They serve the public, do they not?

Comment: My (and Wikipedia's) understanding of the word “public transport” and of the question at hand is that it is about *shared* passenger services. But if you want to extend the scope a little bit, registered taxis, car hire firms and private limo services also serve the public and it feels odd to mention Uber while leaving those out. Without that, I think the answer would be better without the last sentence…

Comment: @Relaxed By that definition, no, Uber is not public transport. I think I'm going to leave the mention, as it may be useful to someone else, or perhaps even the OP (who I presume is going to have a higher priority on making his flight than whether he does so on mass transit)!

Comment: Fair enough but then why only Uber? And why be cocky about it when I pointed out it wasn't a public transport option? We don't need to debate this for hours but I still think editing your answer would improve it.

Comment: Just an update: Star of America is no longer operating, but GoExpress now has early service with an airport arrival at 5:30 am on certain days.